# Unexpected speed-up on .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

For the last few months I have been running a processor-intensive 
program which I wrote in C# and which is called Zeros6.

The approximate elapsed time, so far, has been 157 days and the total 
processor time is 1,217 days. [Some details of the computer: Intel 
Core i7 2600 / 3.4 GHz / 4 cores + hyperthreading -> 8 processors.]

I wrote the program using Visual Studio Express 2010 and version 4 of 
the .NET Framework (I think).

Anyway, today I decided to install Visual Studio Express 2012. The 
installer installed version 4.5 of the .NET Framework and then 
requested a reboot to continue the installation. I stopped the Zeros6 
program and OKed the reboot. After the reboot Zeros6 restarted 
automatically as usual and the Visual Studio installation continued 
and soon finished. I was then shocked to discover that Zeros6 was 
running MUCH faster than it usually runs. A speed indicator which is 
usually fairly steady at 5.5 (picoseconds per digit) had dropped to 
2.0 - I had never seen it lower than 5.34. I then stopped and started 
the program a few times, and rebooted the computer again, but the 
speed improvement continues to persist. If we call the old speed 100%, 
the new speed is 275% !!

I am curious to know what is going on.

Some declarations...

```
uint[] digits;  
uint   startI;  
uint   stopI;  
public static readonly int  bigPowerIncrement = 34;  
public static readonly uint myBase = 1000000000;
```

All 8 processors spend most of their time doing this...

```
  {
    ulong carry = 0;
    unchecked
    {
      for (uint i = startI; i < stopI; i++)
      {
        ulong m = ((ulong)digits[i] << bigPowerIncrement) | carry;
        carry = m/myBase;
        if ((digits[i] = (uint)(m - myBase*carry)) < 1000000)
        { // do this about one time in 1000...
          h.specials[h.specialCount++] = i;
        }
      } // i loop
    } // unchecked
    h.carry = carry;
  }
```

Comment: I am curious to know what is going on. " - they improved something....some locking mechanisms were improved...

Comment: I do not know if your code involves anything parallel but [here is the improvements on TPL](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/1615555D-287C-4159-8491-8E5644C43CBA/TPL%20Performance%20Improvements%20in%20.Net%204.5.pdf). Another one about [better garbage collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx). The entire list on performance improvements [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882452.aspx). A better answer is possible only if we see `specials` and `h`

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know *exactly* what improved, but there were quite a few improvements in .NET 4.5.  As it's an in-place upgrade to .NET 4, you'll benefit from those improvements.

> h.specials[h.specialCount++] = i;

If `h.specials` is a `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>`, for example, this alone could be the improvement.  The `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` type was dramatically improved in .NET 4.5.

It could also simply be one new or changed JIT optimization that is now benefiting you that was not before, or many other things.

Comment: Do you know where I could find some details about the improvements on ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: Here is some info on improvements http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/08/10235147.aspx

Comment: There were also huge improvements to COM interop, so if anything's using COM here, that would do it, too...